# Repository Pattern Implementation for Blog-Post with photos application

Tags: go, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

Consider a application that allows you to create, list and view blog-posts with photos.

However the application also gives a place where user can view all the photos they have added in all of their blog posts. User can also update captions of these photos individually.

Note we do not want the user to be able to add or delete or update a photo on its own. They can only do so in context of a blog.

For this purpose I need a list, update, create blog-post (with photos) API. I also need a seperate list and updateCaption API for the photos.

I am trying to understand how do I fit this in a repository pattern and DDD.
Considering repository is created per domain aggregate, I feel the best way is to have two repositories blogpost and photo. The `blogpost repository` has methods to update/create/list blog post with photos. And another `photo repository` which simply has a list and updateCaption method. Is this a correct implementation?

One concern that I have for this implementation is that I have `photo` as an aggregate root and as a entity in `blogpost` aggregate and it might not be a correct DDD/repository-pattern implementation.

**In pkg `repository/blogpost/`**

```golang
// in entity.go file
type BlogPost struct {
    ID      string
    Name    string
    Author  string
    Content string
    Photos  []Photo
}

type Photo struct {
    ID      string
    Caption string
    URL     string
}

// repository.go
type repository interface {
    CreateBlogPost(context.Context, BlogPost) (BlogPost, error)
    UpdateBlogPost(context.Context, BlogPost) (BlogPost, error)
    ListBlogPosts(context.Context) ([]BlogPost, error)
}
```

**In pkg `repository/photo/`**

```golang
// in entity.go file
type Photo struct {
    ID         string
    Caption    string
    BlogPostID int
    URL        string
}

// in repository.go file
type repository interface {
    UpdateCaption(ctx context.Context, ID string, Caption string) (Photo, error)
    ListPhotos(context.Context) ([]Photo, error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in duplicating the `Photo` struct/repository. What you have is two different repositories. `Photo` is linked to a blog post using an ID.

What you can do is handle this relation outside of the repository package. When a create request comes in, create the post in the `blogpost` repository and then create the photos in the `photo` repository linked to the `Post` ID.

To get the photos for a post, create a method that returns photos linked to the given blog post:

`photo` repository:

```
type repository interface {
    CreatePhoto(context.Context, Photo) (Photo, error)
    UpdateCaption(ctx context.Context, ID string, Caption string) (Photo, error)
    ListPhotos(context.Context) ([]Photo, error)
    PostPhotos(context.Context, postID string) ([]Photo, error)
}
```

To create and retrieve posts and photos, consider a package name `service` as an example:

`service`:

```
func CreatePost(post BlogPost, photos []Photo) error {
    p, err := blogpostRepo.CreateBlogPost(context.TODO(), post)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, photo := range photos {
        photo.PostID = p.ID
        _, err := photoRepo.CreatePhoto(context.TODO(), photo)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}

func GetPost(id string) (BlogPost, error) {
    post, err := blogpostRepo.GetPost(id)
    // handle error
    postPhotos, err := photoRepo.PostPhotos(id)
    // handle error
}
```

You should have different structs in your `service` layer to avoid sending out repository structs. Basically convert repository structs to service structs and service structs to repository structs.

It's also a good idea to run create methods inside of a transaction. You can use dependency injection to inject the transaction.

Comment: thank you for looking into this Navid. Does this not beat the purpose of Repository pattern all together? As far as I understood, as per DDD, we will want that all the details of creating a blogpost (including its relationship with photos) are encapsulated in the blogpost repository so that the service layer is not worried about the DB implementation. Is that an incorrect understanding?

Comment: That depends on how you separate each component into different domains. Is `Photo` a separate domain or is it a small part of a `BlogPost`? How the logic is different? How coupled they are. And as for your last point, `service` doesn't need to worry about the DB complementation as it is hidden from it. Only the API is exposed through an interface not how it is implemented. `Photo` can exist on a different database or a file and `service` would not care or need to.